# App Table Design is not correct error appeared

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have designed a form according to our given assignment. But the following error message is shown:

**App Table Design is not correct:
NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]"}**

The assignment is as follows (Design a Web page for customers for renting the page).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2><span style="background-color:#000080; color:#ff6600">Rent Toys</span></h2>
  
<form>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="tname">Toy name:</label></td>
            <td>
                <select id="tname" name="tname">
                    <option value="Bicycle">Bicycle</option>
                    <option value="Train">Train</option>
                    <option value="Doll">Doll</option>
                    <option value="Teddy Bear">Teddy Bear</option>
                    <option value="Kite">5</option>
                    <option value="Airplane">Airplane</option>
                    <option value="Model Car">Model Car</option>
                    <option value="Art Farm">Art Farm</option>
                    <option value=" Lego Mind storms"> Lego Mind storms</option>
                    <option value="Speak and Spell">Speak and Spell</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="ttype">Customer Name:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="ttype" name="ttype" pattern="[A-Za-z]{5,}" onblur="blurFunction()">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="ttype">Rent Start Date</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="date" id="Rdate" name="Rdate" >
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="minage">Rent Tenure</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="RTdate" name="RTdate"  pattern="[0-9]">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="maxage">Number of Toys available</label></td>
            <td>    
                <input type="text" id="RTdate" name="RTdate"  pattern="[0-9]">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="price">Enter Number of Toys</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="quant" name="quant" >
            </td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit Query" onclick="calculate()">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</form> 
<script>
// No focus = Changes the background color of input to red
function blurFunction() {
  document.getElementById("ttype").style.background = "red";
}

function calculate(){
   var costperday=100;
   var qty=document.getElementById('quant').value;
   var rtdate=document.getElementById('RTdate').value;
   var show=qty*rtdate*costperday;
   confirm(show);
   confirm("Thank you for order Mr/Ms/Mrs:"+document.getElementById('ttype').value);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you getting this error from? The code you've presented doesn't seem to have any error and behaves as intended.

Comment: use `.valueAsNumber` instead of `.value` for dates if you want the exact milliseconds number for your calculations, although it has no relation to the error, but instead `var show=qty*rtdate*costperday;` will hold the `NaN` value because it's a string multiplied by a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a lot of research I found out the solution (might not be general i.e for every one) that removal of  tag makes the code acceptable for the compiler..... Thank You

Comment: which tag we need to remove?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code so you pass the DOM element to the function

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="ttype" name="ttype" pattern="[A-Za-z]{5,}" onblur="blurFunction(this)">
```

Javascript

```
function blurFunction(e) {
   e.style.background = "red";
}
```

Comment: What made you think that causes a problem?!, although his implementation is not the good way, but that function should not produce any errors

Comment: well i tried changing the code as suggested but didn't help !! .... i think the compiler that is reviewing my code has this error ..... I can't understand what does the error message App Table Design is not correct: NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]"} mean!!

Comment: I know it was a working function but this is the cleaner way. Also, Bane2000 answer is more fitting in this case I guess.

Comment: The cleaner way then should use no attributes for events, everything should be in the js section `document.querySelector("#ttype").onblur = e=> e.target.style.background = "red";`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like error from Selenium(probably). It is looking for xpath: ***//body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]***
but in your code table is wrapped inside of form element so xpath should look something like this: ***//body/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]***

Change xpath or change your page structure in order to match required path

Answer (score 0):

use `thead`as a table heading.`<label for="tname">Toy name:</label>` all headings add in `thead`

```
<thead>
<tr>
  <th scope="col"><label for="tname">Toy name:</label></th>
</tr>
```